# troubles to get coordinates xperia (android 8) using GoogleApiClient

Tags: android

I'm working with a Sony xPeria Android 8, I'm having troubles to get coordinates just with this model, I'm using com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient , Some one Idea why with this model?

Answer (score 0):

We added a Handler. Special tanks to Hugo Leyva for this answer

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Log.e(_TAG, "Error with permissions");
                showSettingsAlert(); //force permission
            }else{
                Log.w(_TAG, "Permission its ok");
                //mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient); // get last Locations
                if(mLocation!=null){
                    Log.w(_TAG, "mLocation is not null");
                    Log.w(_TAG, "Latitude : "+mLocation.getLatitude()+" , Longitude : "+mLocation.getLongitude());
                    //Toast.makeText(this.mContext ,"Latitude : "+mLocation.getLatitude()+" , Longitude : "+mLocation.getLongitude() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    latitud = mLocation.getLatitude();
                    longitud = mLocation.getLongitude();

                    setLatitud(latitud);
                    setLongitud(longitud);
                    Log.w(_TAG, "Setting Latitud:" + getLatitud() + " Longitud:" + getLongitud() );

                }else{
                    Log.e(_TAG, "mLocation is NULL!");
                    Toast.makeText(mContext ,"Please enable GPS" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mGoogleApiClient.reconnect();
                    startLocationUpdates();
                }
            }


        }
    }, 5000);
```